# Retrieving Data from Database - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am able to save data into my database using the code below. When the user clicks on the checkbox, the name of the item is displayed and stored in the database. But my problem now is, when I am editing the stored data, I am able to retrieve the items which were checked (the items selected and saved previously)  but the JS for appending code doesn't run.

When I uncheck and check it again, it works normally.

When editing, the items saved in the database are checked but the JS part of the code which displays the name of the item selected doesn't run. Why is that happening?

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label"> Name</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="name" value="{!!$item->products['name']!!}" placeholder="  Name" name="name" required>
  </div>
</div>
<input onclick="return data(this)" data-food="{{$product->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" id="{!! $product->id !!}" name="{!! $product->name !!}" 
value="{!! $product->price !!}"  @foreach ($product->emps as $deliver)   @if($product->id == $deliver->id) checked @endif @endforeach  />
```

**JS**

```
function data(item)
{ 
  var ad = JSON.parse(item.dataset.food);

  if(item.checked == true)  {
    $('.container').append(
    '<div class="shipment_container" > '+ 
    '<p  class="name" >'+ad.name+'</p>'+
    '</div>');
  }
  else {
    $(".container.shipment_container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: why `dataset.stuff` when the attribute is `data-food`? Also use single quotes to wrap the json in the html

Comment: I have made the edits in my code please @charlietfl

Comment: `item.dataset.food` not `item.dataset.item` because the data attribute is food

Comment: @YouneL, i have made the edits but then my items are still not showing. The items are suppose to show on document load

Comment: @charlietfl, how do i retrieve my item on the container on document load?

Comment: Why are you putting them in an attribute for an input if you want to access the data on page load? Can assign the output to a javascript variable if that's what you need

Comment: @charlietfl, can you provide an answer in code form, i don't really understand the english

Comment: `var data = <?= json_encode($array) ?>;`

Answer (score 1):

I think You want to show your product in container element if it was already checked, You can Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // get input id
    var item = $('#{!! $product->id !!}');

    // parse json
    var ad = JSON.parse(item.data('food'));
    if(item.prop("checked") )  {
        $('.container').append(
            '<div class="shipment_container" > '+ 
            '<p  class="name" >'+ad.name+'</p>'+
            '</div>');
    }
    else {
        $(".container.shipment_container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: This is not solving my issue. please understand what i am trying to achieve. When user clicks on edit page, the items previously selected should appear on the container. Currently, i have the checkbox checked but the items do  not appear on the container

Comment: My container is still empty upon page load although the checkbox are selected

Comment: Use `item.attr('data-food')` instead of `item.data('food')`

Comment: i am sure this line `var item = $('#{{!! $product->id !!}}');` has an issue because when i alert item right after this line, i get an error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #{10}`
`

Comment: Yes my mistake,  change it to this: `var item = $('#{!! $product->id !!}');`

Comment: this is what is happening now,  this line `var item = $('#{!! $product->id !!}');` is only returning the last food in the database even though it is not the selected food

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159352/discussion-between-younel-and-xamarindevil).